# How does typeid work and how do objects store class information?

Tags: c++, typeid

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid

This seems to be a mystery to me: how does a compiler stores information about the type of an object ? Basically an empty class, once instantiated, has not a zero size in memory.

Comment: C++ objects are never zero-size (except that base class sub-object can be). This isn't because of `typeid`, though, it's because if you created an array of something that was zero-size, all the objects would be at the same address. It's useful as a property of the language that distinct objects each have their own address, hence no zero-size objects. This doesn't matter so much for base class sub-objects, if only because every is used to the idea that several base classes of the same object may be at the same address - that's what normally happens in single inheritance anyway.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How it is stored is implementation-defined. There are many completely different ways to do it.

However, for non-polymorphic types *nothing* needs to be stored. For non-polymorphic types `typeid` returns information about the *static* type of the expression, i.e. its *compile-time* type. The type is always known at compile-time, so there's no need to associate any additional information with specific objects (just like for `sizeof` to work you don't really need to store the object size anywhere). "An empty object" that you mention in your question would be an object of non-polymorphic type, so there's no need to store anything in it and there's no problem with it having zero size. (Meanwhile, polymorphic objects are never really "empty" and never have "zero size in memory".)

For polymorphic types `typeid` does indeed return the information about the *dynamic* type of the expression, i.e. about its *run-time* type. To implement this something has to be stored inside the actual object at run-time. As I said above, different compilers implement it differently. In MSVC++, for one example, the VMT pointer stored in each polymorphic object points to a data structure that contains the so called RTTI - run-time type information about the object - in addition to the actual VMT.

The fact that you mention zero size objects in your question probably indicates that you have some misconceptions about what `typeid` can and cannot do. Remember, again, `typeid` is capable of determining the actual (i.e. dynamic) type of the object for *polymorphic types only*. For non-polymorphic types `typeid` cannot determine the actual type of the object and reverts to primitive compile-time functionality.

Comment: that's the #1 reason people have been whining about C++, because it's a slight loss of memory control. While I'm briefly taking the side of the control-freak programmer, how is the type check really done, is it some integer ? Where can I see the actual implementation ?

Comment: @gokoon: If your compiler doesn't document it, you'll need to reverse engineer from generated code (e.g. compile to asm).

Comment: @gokoon:  You can see the actual implementation in Open Source/Free C++ compilers, and there are some out there.  Not all compilers have to do things the same way, so if you're interested in a particular compiler, like Visual C++, you'll have to research that one in particular.

Comment: @gokoon: I don't understand.  I've presented a way (or theory, if you like) in my answer to piggy-back typeid on top of virtual functions.  Then when you ask how your compiler "really does" typeid, we say to check a real compiler itself.  I'm not sure what else we can give you.

Comment: There is no problem at all: I just thought typeid was part of the C++ standard. But I still wonder if it's absolutely necessary to store some byte of extra information on each object about the type of the object. Since the compiler already does type checking etc, I wonder why is it still necessary to store those informations.

Comment: @gokoon: typeid is part of the standard, but the standard makes requirements about how it behaves, not about how it must be implemented.  The compiler does *static-type* checking.  The dynamic-type of an object depends on what happens at runtime.

Comment: when exactly is an object considered "polymorphic"?

Comment: @Youda008: By definition, a polymorphic class is a class that has at least one virtual function. A polymorphic object is an object of polymorphic class type.

Comment: @gokoon Consider that you have array of God knows what, you want to iterate through the array and if you find a donut, you want to eat it. If you want to call the eat method on it the only way to know if you have a donut is for the program to store a pointer to the vtable, which stores what type it is. You can check this with a dynamic cast or typeid thing. It's impossible to know its type at compile time, because you've thrown a whole bunch of objects into an array at runtime.

Answer (score 6):

Imagine every class as if it has this virtual method, but only if it already has one other virtual, and one object is created for each type:

```
extern std::type_info __Example_info;
struct Example {
  virtual std::type_info const& __typeid() const {
    return __Example_info;
  }
};
// "__" used to create reserved names in this pseudo-implementation
```

Then imagine any use of *typeid* on an object, `typeid(obj)`, becomes `obj.__typeid()`.  Use on pointers similarly becomes `pointer->__typeid()`.  Except for use on null pointers (which throws bad_typeid), the pointer case is identical to the non-pointer case after dereferencing, and I won't mention it further.  When applied directly on a type, imagine that the compiler inserts a reference directly to the required object: `typeid(Example)` becomes `__Example_info`.

If a class does not have RTTI (i.e. it has no virtuals; e.g. NoRTTI below), then imagine it with an identical *__typeid* method that is **not** virtual.  This allows the same transformation into method calls as above, relying on virtual or non-virtual dispatch of those methods, as appropriate; it also allows some virtual method calls to be transformed into non-virtual dispatch, as can be performed for any virtual method.

```
struct NoRTTI {};  // a hierarchy can mix RTTI and no-RTTI, just as use of
                   // virtual methods can be in a derived class even if the base
                   // doesn't contain any
struct A : NoRTTI { virtual ~A(); };  // one virtual required for RTTI
struct B : A {};  // ~B is virtual through inheritance

void typeid_with_rtti(A &a, B &b) {
  typeid(a); typeid(b);
  A local_a;  // no RTTI required: typeid(local_a);
  B local_b;  // no RTTI required: typeid(local_b);

  A &ref = local_b;
  // no RTTI required, if the compiler is smart enough: typeid(ref)
}
```

Here, *typeid* must use RTTI for both parameters (B could be a base class for a later type), but does not need RTTI for either local variable because the dynamic type (or "runtime type") is absolutely known.  This matches, not coincidentally, how virtual calls can avoid virtual dispatch.

```
struct StillNoRTTI : NoRTTI {};

void typeid_without_rtti(NoRTTI &obj) {
  typeid(obj);
  StillNoRTTI derived; typeid(derived);
  NoRTTI &ref = derived; typeid(ref);

  // typeid on types never uses RTTI:
  typeid(A); typeid(B); typeid(NoRTTI); typeid(StillNoRTTI);
}
```

Here, use on either *obj* or *ref* will correspond to *NoRTTI!*  This is true even though the former may be of a derived class (*obj* could really be an instance of *A* or *B*) and even though *ref* is definitely of a derived class.  All of the other uses (the last line of the function) will also be resolved statically.

Note that in these example functions, each *typeid* uses RTTI or not as the function name implies.  (Hence the commented-out uses in *with_rtti*.)

Comment: I will need to read that more than again. I don't set this as the accepted answer as it seems quite detailed, but the answer below are quite more explained than using brutal examples.

Comment: @gokoon: Ah, you had it as the accepted answer for a moment... :)  I find it most effective to weave explanation in with practical examples, especially when you can try them yourself (e.g. by applying the typeid(obj) to obj.__typeid() conversion manually), but diff'rent strokes.  (I did just update trying to focus on clarity.)

Answer (score 1):

Even when you do not use type information, an empty class will not have zero bytes, it always has something, if I remember correct the standard demands that.

I believe the typeid is implemented similar to a vtable pointer, the object will have a "hidden" pointer to its typeid.

Comment: There is no need to add to every instance to support typeid: you can just use a vtable entry, since each instance already points to a dynamic-type-specific vtable.  This is why you can only use typeid to get the dynamic type of an object if it has at least one virtual method.

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions in your one question.

In C++ objects is something that occupies memory. If it does not occupy any memory - it is not an object (although base class sub-object can occupy no space). So, an object has to occupy at least 1 byte.

A compiler does not store any type information unless your class has a virtual function. In that case a pointer to type information is often stored at a negative offset in the virtual function table. Note that the standard does not mention any virtual tables or type information format so it is purely an implementation detail.